# Streaming mp3 file from server in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer, audio-streaming

I am trying to stream mp3 file from my centOS based server , I have uploaded the file to server and tried opening it in AvPlayer , however it actually downloads it and plays it, when I open the same link in browser it is able to stream the file, it starts playing in 5 seconds around. 
Is there any solution which can do the same in iOS app using swift ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used php for stream that mean IOS app will play the mp3 file via stream.php:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
$filePath = $dirPath . "/songname.mp3";
$strContext=stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http'=>array(
        'method'=>'GET',
        'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n"
        )
    )
);
$fpOrigin=fopen($filePath, 'rb', false, $strContext);
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="songname.mp3"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filePath));
while(!feof($fpOrigin)){
  $buffer=fread($fpOrigin, 4096);
  echo $buffer;
  flush();
}
fclose($fpOrigin);
```

Then I pass the url to swift: http://domain/stream.php

Comment: ok will give it a try , didnt think it can be solved this way :D

Comment: If this method is working for you, all you need is to add a `Content-Disposition` header.  Let your web server do this... doing it by invoking PHP is inefficient.  You also need to be very careful here... depending on how you're specifying your file names in parameters, there is the potential for your PHP script to return arbitrary files from disk.